# Identify discriminator circuit?

Tags: detection, frequency-modulation, demodulation, detector

The Dynaco FM-3 tuner uses what appears to be a Foster-Seeley discriminator with one diode reversed, or, if you prefer, a ratio detector without the third coil and stabilizing capacitor. The Dynaco marketing material and user manual uses the term 'discriminator' consistently throughout.

I don't find this variant discussed in the RDH, or Cook & Liffey, which are my only FM texts of enough depth to cover this sort of thing. Does it have a name? How does it work? And what are its salient properties?

Schematic (also [here](http://s9.photobucket.com/user/Bob01605/media/DynacoFM3schematic.jpg.html)):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

It is indeed a Foster-Seeley discriminator, by the arrangement of the coils and the inductive and capacitative coupling between them, which produces the characteristic voltage-difference AM, but the method of demodulating the AM is different by the reversal of one of the diodes.

Comment: I don't really believe in doing this in general, but I'm marking this answer as correct in default of a better one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty similar to a later (postwar) version developed by [Seeley](http://fmamradios.com/Ratio_Detector.html), which he called a ratio detector:

[image]

Comment: Except that it doesn't have C4. I did mention that in the question. C4 is a fundamental feature of the ratio detector. Without it there is no ratio to detect as far as I can see.

Comment: @EJP couldn't C4 be regarded as part of the two series capacitors junctioning at point P.

Comment: @Andyaka Not unless they were a million times the value. C4 is typically 25uF and does two things: provides a constant DC voltage so that a voltage ratio can be detected when the phase shifts, and the time constant is chosen to also provide AM rejection. The two you mention are 47pF each. They are a capacitative centre-tap to ground the balanced discriminator.

Comment: @EJP I see your point..the cutoff of the RC is 65kHz.